# How to know which users are logged in on TYPO3

Tags: statistics, typo3

Does anyone know if there is a way to do this, or an extension that displays who is logged in at the Front End and at the Back End.

Something that displays a list of the logged-in users (both fe_users and be_users).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In TYPO3 you can also check who is online in real-time :

1. Connect as **Admin**
2. Click on **User Admin** in **ADMIN TOOLS** part
3. Change **Compare User Settings** by **List Users Online**

You will see **Who Is Online**.

Check the demo site to try : http://demo.typo3.org

Comment: Thanks, a few days ago I found that option (a little bit hidden) and it solves the problem for the BE Users. Now I'm considering develop a BE module with log for both type of users since I didn't find anything for the FE Users.

Answer (score 0):

every user has his own session. Table be_session. Look at it. you got every info you need

Comment: Thanks. You're right there is the info. But it is possible to see this info directly from the BE?,I saw it using phpMyAdmin.

Comment: for example system logs. You can see who has logged when and did he log out